# What is the difference between using the & symbol and using nesting when defining a more detailed class?

Tags: sass

What is the difference between the code examples below:

Using nesting:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 2.5em;

    btn-small {
        padding: .4em 1.7em;
    }
```

Using the & symbol:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em 2.5em;

    &.btn-small {
        padding: .4em 1.7em;
    }
```

When should I use one over the other?

Comment: You can see how your scss will compile using this online tool: http://www.sassmeister.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` symbol will concatenate the CSS (without whitespace).

```
.btn {
    btn-small {
        padding: .4em 1.7em;
}}
```

converts to

```
.btn btn-small {
  padding: .4em 1.7em;
}
```

whereas

```
.btn {
    &.btn-small {
        padding: .4em 1.7em;
}}
```

converts to

```
.btn.btn-small {
  padding: .4em 1.7em;
}
```

This is particularly useful when using pseudo classes.

**scss**

```
a {
    &:hover {
        color:yellow;
}}
```

**css**

```
a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use & when you want to make more specific selector, for elements that has more classes. For example you can write something like this:

```
.button {
      &:visited{}
      &:hover{}
      &:active {}
   }
```

This compiles to:

```
.button:visited{}
.button:hover{}
.button:active{}
```

And if you left out the & from this, it would compile to this, with space between which isn't the same

```
.button :hover
```